# Zooming to coordinates on raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, extents, zoom

I have a raster file with extent values set up:

```
Top: 6,185,000.0

Bottom: 6,175,000.0

Left: 1,340,000.0

Right: 1,345,000.0
```

I have to find a point on my raster at the following coordinate:

```
1,344,076.7

6,179,038.1
```

How can I find it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "Go To XY" tool. I had to set "meters" as units both in the tool and at the bottom of the map window, they started out as degrees.

[image]